# Why do stepper motor controllers vary so much in size?

Tags: stepper-driver

Most stepper motor controllers that I see look something like this: [https://www.amazon.com/DEVMO-DM542T-Leadshine-Stepper-Controller/dp/B07S5XN5S4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07S5XN5S4)  This is a large unit, at 6.89 x 4.13 x 1.57 inches; 10.02 Ounces (284g).  It also has large fins on the back, indicating that it dissipates a lot of heat.  In terms of specs, it advertises an output peak current of 1-4.2A, and input voltage of 20-50VDC

On the other hand, I see a unit like https://www.pololu.com/product/3730.  It is far smaller, at 1.3 inches x 1.2 inches, and weighs only 4.9g.  It does not have any fins or fans.  But it seems to advertise similar specs at 4A continuous current and 50V max operating voltage.

What difference in design can explain this disparity?  What advantages do the bigger units have that explains why they need to be 50x bigger and heavier?

Comment: You could not expected a small, lightweight and weak stepping motor and a big, heavy, fast and strong motor to work with the same small controller. A controller for powerful motors should deliver more current and voltage, the power loss converted to heat is much bigger and a larger surface is needed to dissipate the bigger power loss without destroying the controller by too high temperatures.

Comment: I agree that I would not normally expect a small controller to drive a big motor.

But if that's true, I would expect this difference in performance to be reflected in the specs for the two controllers: I would expect the smaller controller to have more limited specs.

What's confusing is that these two controllers have similar specs, despite their very large size difference. Is the large unit just an enormous heat sink around a similarly capable MOSFET?

Answer (score 1):

Module 3730 is "more" complicated to drive.

> Power dissipation considerations
> The High-Power Stepper Motor Driver 36v4 can deliver up to 4 A continuous per phase under typical conditions, but the actual current it can deliver will depend on how well you can keep the module cool. The driver’s printed circuit board is designed to draw heat out of the MOSFETs, but **performance can be improved by adding a heat sink or forced air flow**. (Conversely, performance will be reduced in applications that limit heat dissipation, such as high ambient temperatures or operation in enclosures.) With sufficient additional cooling, the driver can deliver up to 6 A per phase before exceeding the 1 W power ratings of the 30 mΩ current sense resistors.

DM542T has the lowest count of wire pins ("direct" commands, not programmable). [Example](https://vslot-poland.com/how-to-connet-arduino-to-nema).

Answer (score 1):

For start, the DM542T has a case which limits air circulating around the (internal) PCB. Put the 3730 module inside a case, and you will discover that a heat sink is necessary. Maybe your application does not need a cased controller.

Then, other considerations must be done. If you have a part delivering "4A continuous", does it mean "continuously for an hour" or "continuously for a month"? The heat generation of the power mosfets (final stage) depends on internal resistance and the frequency driving them. For example, you can lower the frequency, but you will get more (audio) noise. Or you can lower the internal resistance, but it will cost more.

As a personal impression, the DM542T is more serious and professional, and can deliver 4A @50V without being too stressed, while the 3730 is more delicate (just an impression). This "impression" does not consider other features, like the many more functions of the 3730.